What is the Pythonic way to use match/case statements with classes that only provide getter methods and computed value methods?
I have several classes that I don't own. These classes provide methods to access internal information, rather than attributes or properties.
For example a class might look something like this:
class Foo:
  def __init__(self, a, b) -> None:
    self._a = a
    self._b = b

  def a(self): return self._a
  def b(self): return self._b
  def c(self): return self._a + self._b

I would like to be able to use match/case to do something like this:
foo_list = [
  Foo(1,0),
  Foo(0,1),
  Foo(1,2),
  Foo(3,3),
  Foo(3,2),
]

for foo in foo_list:
  match foo:
    case Foo(a=a, b=0):
      print(f'first a = {a}, b = {foo.b}')
    case Foo(a=0, b=b):
      print(f'second a = {foo.a}, b = {b}')
    case Foo(a=1, b=b):
      print(f'third a = {foo.a}, b = {b}')
    case Foo(a=a, b=3):
      print(f'forth a = {a}, b = {foo.b}')
    case Foo(a=a, b=b, c=5):
      print(f'fifth a = {a}, b = {b}, c = {foo.c}')

However this does not work since the case statements matching an object expect constructor-like syntax where the named arguments are attributes or properties not getter methods,  which is what I have.
What is the Pythonic way to match/case statements with classes such as this?

I don't think you can. As you say the Foo(bar="baz") syntax is for Foo instances with a bar attribute having the value "baz". Class patterns have no way to do what you're asking.

You can do: case Foo(a=a, b=b_method) if b_method() == 0, etc. If we take your surface claim I have several classes that I don't own., then there is no amount of hackery that can support comparing methods in match statements; I don't think there are metaclass hooks that allow you to modify what match...case does.

@dROOOze,  yes your case statement will work, but is this the best / pythonic approach?  See my answer below.  If I add a_p and b_p as a properties of Foo,  I can simply use case Foo(a_p=a, b_p=0)

Adding extra property attributes outside of the class definition itself, to classes you don't own (as per your words), definitely is not Pythonic.

@dROOOze Hmmm ... is that true?  Many languages support the idea of extension methods,  which is adding methods to pre-existing classes with out subclassing.  This is a different from outright monkey patching where you might replace  a method. I will have to do some research on that to see if that is truly considered non-Pythonic ... thanks for the comments!

I feel like those would be the type of languages which make a clear distinction between libraries and apps, and which a compiled app is its own stand-alone unit that doesn't share a runtime with other apps. Python's "import anything" (anything can be a library) and "introspect anything" philosophy is quite different, and adding unexpected attributes to a base class is not meaningfully different to replacing attributes, in that it will present surprises which are not visible from the source code.

Since it seems to be clear that foo is always a Foo and nothing else, and if you use most of its attributes in all cases, you could simply match on a tuple (foo.a(), foo.b(), foo.c()), not on foo itself:
match (foo.a(), foo.b(), foo.c()):
    case (a, 0, _): ...
    case (0, b, _): ...
    # ...
    case (a, b, 5): ...

However, this means that if you add new cases where you use another method d() that you didn't use before, you would have to include it in the matched tuple and update every case even if does not need d:
match (foo.a(), foo.b(), foo.c(), foo.d()):
    case (a, 0, _, _): ...
    case (0, b, _, _): ...
    # ...
    case (a, b, 5, _): ...
    case (_, _, _, d): ...

You could avoid that by creating an object wrapping foo and exposing its methods as attributes:
class FooAttributes:
    def __init__(self, foo: Foo):
        self.a = foo.a()
        self.b = foo.b()
        self.c = foo.c()
        self.d = foo.d()

Here you could get creative with using getattr and setattr and using a list of strings to specify which methods to expose.
Then you could achieve something very close to your original intended code:
F = FooAttributes  # use an alias to shorten the cases

match FooAttributes(foo):
    case F(a=a, b=0): ...
    case F(a=0, b=b): ...
    # ...
    case F(a=a, b=b, c=5): ...
    case F(d=d): ...


Doesn't this mean the match statement has to be a super set of all the possible properties I might want to use in the case statements?  That could get messy if I wanted to match various foo objects with deeply nested properties

and if later on I wanted to add a single case statement that needed to match on foo.d(),  wouldn't I have to update the match and all the existing case statements?

But you agree,  if I wanted to match a case with a specific foo.d() value I would need to re-write the entire statement, right?

and if I want the actual object that is matched,  this does not provide it, right?
Sorry I am not trying to be super critical, just trying to understand the trade-offs

ah, yes I do have the for variable foo which holds the matched object.

A solution I am considering is to add properties to the classes using the property function as shown below.  This seems to work,  but I am not sure if there is at least some naming convention I should follow.
Here is a possible solution that I am considering:
Adding properties such as this
Foo.a_p = property(Foo.a)
Foo.b_p = property(Foo.b)
Foo.c_p = property(Foo.c)

Enables the following to work properly:
  match foo:
    case Foo(a_p=a, b_p=0):
      print(f'first a = {a}, b = {foo.b_p}')
    case Foo(a_p=0, b_p=b):
      print(f'second a = {foo.a_p}, b = {b}')
    case Foo(a_p=1, b_p=b):
      print(f'third a = {foo.a_p}, b = {b}')
    case Foo(a_p=a, b_p=3):
      print(f'forth a = {a}, b = {foo.b_p}')
    case Foo(a_p=a, b_p=b, c_p=5):
      print(f'fifth a = {a}, b = {b}, c = {foo.c_p}')

Another nice feature of adding the extra property to the provided classes is that the class can be used in "sub pattern" matches as well.
For example the following also works:
class Bar:
  def __init__(self, x, y, foo:Foo) ->None:
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.foo = foo

foo1 = Foo(42, 43)
foo2 = Foo(420, 430)

bar_list = [
  Bar(3, 4, foo2),
  Bar(1, 2, foo1)
]

for bar in bar_list:
  match bar:
    case Bar(x=x, foo=Foo(a_p=42)):
      print(f"first case extracted the value x = {x} from the matched Bar with x = {bar.x}, y = {bar.y} and nested Foo object foo's a = {bar.foo.a()}, foo's b = {bar.foo.b()}")
    case Bar(foo=Foo(a_p=420, b_p=b)):
      print(f"second case extracted the value b = {b} from the nested Foo object contained in the matched Bar with x = {bar.x}, y = {bar.y} and nested Foo object foo's a = {bar.foo.a()}, foo's b = {bar.foo.b()}")

which prints the following:

second case extracted the value b = 430 from the nested Foo object contained in the matched Bar with x = 3, y = 4 and nested Foo object foo's a = 420, foo's b = 430
first case extracted the value x = 1 from the matched Bar with x = 1, y = 2 and nested Foo object foo's a = 42, foo's b = 43


Another potential solution is this which avoids adding new properties via the property method, but just does not seem as clean as my first answer.  In this case you brute force compare each method call to the value you are looking for rather than using the built in object match pattern.
  match foo:
    case foo if foo.b() == 0:
      print(f'first a = {foo.a()}, b = {foo.b()}')
    case foo if foo.a() == 0:
      print(f'second a = {foo.a()}, b = {foo.b()}')
    case foo if foo.a() == 1:
      print(f'third a = {foo.a()}, b = {foo.b()}')
    case foo if foo.b() == 3:
      print(f'forth a = {foo.a()}, b = {foo.b()}')
    case foo if foo.c() == 5:
      print(f'fifth a = {foo.a()}, b = {foo.b()}, c = {foo.c()}')```

